# DataRow Filtering Special Characters

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in C# that is filtered using the following method;

```
    private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
        if (nNameRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "em_netname LIKE '%" +searchBox.Text+ "%'";
        }
        if (deptRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "em_dept LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (sNameRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "em_name LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (initRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "em_init LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";
        }

        // If the search box is not empty the user cannot add a new employee
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
        {
            newEmpButton.IsEnabled = false;
            newEmpDisabledLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        } else
        {
            newEmpButton.IsEnabled = true;
            newEmpDisabledLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

This all works fine until a user enters something into the grid that I do not account for. For example if the `em_netname` is equal to `JohnSmith` then this is filtered no problem when the user enters, for example, `Joh` or `JohnSm`.

My issue comes when, for whatever reason, a netname is entered so that `em_netname` is equal to something such as `John.Smith.` or `John,Smith`. When the user searches for `JohnSm` this doesn't appear as of course there is a full stop in the netname.

My question is how best to handle this situation within C#?

Comment: Ideally you would use the [Levenshtein Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to show similar results, an implementation of which in C#  can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.23)

Comment: `nNameRad.IsChecked == true` is the same than `nNameRad.IsChecked`

Comment: Why going into so much of complexity? This is a know issue with First Name & Last Name search issue. So if you have noticed all the major websites have two textboxes for search First Name & Last Name separately. You can also divide the search in two textboxes, First Name & Last Name. That will be an easy implementation and user friendly.

Comment: @GaganJaura This problem is not limited to Names. For example, a Company name maybe `T.A.T Smiths` and we encounter the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the whitespace in the select with

```
WHERE 
    em_name LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'
    OR
    REPLACE(em_name, ',', '') LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'
    OR
    REPLACE(em_name, '.', '') LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'
```

so it matches the search for first name and last name concatenated

Comment: My issue isn't with removing whitespace but with removing special characters such as `,` and `.`

Comment: @CBreeze well the same function will work for those as well

Comment: Ah ok that's great. Could you show me an example of how that would fit into my example of `dv.RowFilter = "em_init LIKE '%" + searchBox.Text + "%'";` please? Where would the replace fit into this statement?

Comment: Also the only issue with this is that although this replaces special characters in the searchbox, it does not remove them from the datagrid column contents. So if there is a genuine case where someone is named `John.Smith` they will still not be found if the user searches `John Smith`

Comment: you can add 3 'cases' for the unreplaced name, the ',' replaced name and the '.' replaced name with OR statements in your SQL where clause. As for the code example: at the moment I'm at work on a mac at the office, so not tested! If you are in a hurry just test your code with a SQL development tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SOUNDEX functionality.

Soundex is an algorithm that converts words to an encoded string based on the way the word is pronounced. This allows you to compare words based on pronunciation instead of binary matches. For example, Zach and Zack are pronounced exactly the same way. However, the string "Zach" does not equal the string "Zack" which means that a normal search would not mark them as a match. After running "Zach" and "Zack" through Soundex you will see that they both have the same encoding and treated as same.

So, in your case the soundex will ignore any punctuation mark and will search the needed string along with others which has similar pronunciation.

Please follow this link to implement it http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/how-do-i-implement-the-soundex-function-in-c/